# REST API jersey Glassfish do not serialize json

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey-2.0, tomcat8

I'm using jersey glassfish 2.0 implementation for restfull web service with tomcat 8.

My web serives work fine but the serialization of my java bean is not correct.
**For example my web service return follow json**

```
{
    "errorCode": 200,
    "obj": "DestinationCountry [img=[], code=3, video=AbstractMultiMediaContent [id=0, name=null, url=null, file=null, contentType=null, comments=null, owner=null, likes=null, tags=null, is=null], guide=Guide [guideTraslation=null, getPoi()=null, ......
}
```

**The right json should be**

```
{
    "errorCode": 200,
    "errorMsg": null,
    "obj": [
        {
            "comparableInfo": null,
            "id": 2195,
            "code": "3",
            "name": "Sudafrica",
            "continent": null,
            "idDestinationCountry": 690,
            "previewImage": {
                "comparableInfo": null,
                "id": 0,
                "name": null,
                "url": "sud_africa_viaggi_diving_2",
                "file": null,
                "contentType": null,
                "comments": null,
                "owner": null,
                "likes": null,
                "tags": null,
                "is": null,
                "numberOfLike": 0
            }
```

,
    .....
    .....

This is my java code

```
@GET
@Path("/guide/id/{idguide}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
public Response getGuideById(@PathParam("idguide") int idguide, @QueryParam("uuid") String uuid)
{

    Response response = null ;
    DCResponse<Guide> dcResp = null  ;
    Configuration conf = ConfigurationFactory.getInstance() ;
    try 
    {
        conf.configurationLoader(UtilsConstants.SYS_CONF_FILE);
        DiveCircleManagerIV2 pm = (DiveCircleManagerIV2) CoreFactory.getInstance(conf.getProperty(DiveCircleConstants.DIVECIRCLE_MANAGER)) ;
        dcResp = pm.findGuideById(idguide) ;
        response = Response.status(dcResp.getErrorCode()).entity(dcResp).build() ;
    } 
    catch (ConfigurationException | IOException | FactoryException | ManagerException e) {
        log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = Response.status(DiveCircleConstants.INTERNAL_ERROR_CODE).build() ;
    }

    return response ;

}
```

Here my pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.divecircle.booking.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>BookingAPI</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.geeoz.ean</groupId>
        <artifactId>ean-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.0d1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudinary</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
        <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>            
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>


  <!-- ###############################################-->
   <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     -->

  <!-- ###############################################-->  



    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.spy</groupId>
        <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cstadvising.utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>Utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>         
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

this is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <display-name>DiveCircle</display-name>




     <listener>
        <description>System Inizilizer</description>
        <listener-class>com.cstadvising.utils.core.listener.SystemContextListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>         
        <init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
          <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyFeature;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.divecircle.restful</param-value>
        </init-param>   
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

    <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
     <param-value>/quartz.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
<!--    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
     -->
</web-app>
```

Any sugestion or solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with MOXy (i.e. `jersey-media-moxy`). It needs to know all type information when serializing. With `DCResponse`, you have a generic type, which is erased at compile time

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DCResponse<T> {

    private int status;
    private String errorMsg;
    private List<T> obj;
```

When the `DCResponse<Guide> dcResp` is compiled, the type is erased, because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). To get around that, Jersey offers the [`GenericEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html), which captures the generic type, and passes it to the serializer. So you would do this

```
DCResponse<Guide> dcResp = dcResp = pm.findGuideById(idguide);
response = Response.status(dcResp.getErrorCode())
        .entity(new GenericEntity<DCResponse<Guide>>(dcResp) {}).build();
```

That should work.

Or if you don't want to have to worry about stuff like this, consider using Jackson, instead of MOXy. Jackson generally doesn't run into problems like this, as it just introspects properties. To use Jackson, you need to get rid of the MOXy (this is important), and add the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then instead of the `MoxyJsonFeature`, you need to register the [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html)